# Go path and setup

Tags: go

I installed go binary for windows 64 and set up Go Paths like

[image: this]

I also downloaded it from git. Why wont it find the go command?

Comment: https://golang.org/doc/install

Answer (score 1):

> I also downloaded it from git

The [Go repo (github.com/golang/go)](https://github.com/golang/go) wouldn't include the go binary.
Only the msi or the archive at [golang.org/dl/](https://golang.org/dl/) would (like [go1.4.1.windows-amd64.zip](https://storage.googleapis.com/golang/go1.4.1.windows-amd64.zip)) would.

You can unzip the archive anywhere, and set `GOROOT` to it, and `%GOROOT%\bin` will point the the go binary.

Answer (score 1):

Add under user variables:
GOPATH: C/:go

Add under systems variable:
C:/go